# Counterspelling with a lower-level spell

Tags: pathfinder-2e, statistics, counterspelling

I'm curious about the utility of counterspelling with low level spells, if one chooses to feat for it. Particularly the feasibility of keeping low-level spells prepared specifically for use as counters. The [rule for counterspell](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=633) in Pathfinder 2E says:

> [Witch, Wizard] You expend a prepared spell to counter the triggering
> creature’s casting of that same spell. You lose your spell slot as if
> you had cast the triggering spell. You then attempt to counteract the
> triggering spell.

Note that the countering spell could theoretically be a lower-level version of the triggering spell.

If a Wizard further takes the [Clever Counterspell feat](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=653), they can use a different spell (again not necessarily of the same level):

> At the GM’s discretion, you can instead use a spell that has an
> opposing trait or that otherwise logically would counter the
> triggering spell (such as using a cold or water spell to counter
> fireball or using remove fear to counter a fear spell). Regardless of
> what spell you expend, you take a –2 penalty to your counteract check,
> though the GM can waive this penalty if the expended spell is
> especially appropriate.

The rule for [counteract checks](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=371) appears to be the following (non-spell portions edited out)

> When attempting a counteract check, add the relevant skill modifier or
> other appropriate modifier to your check against the target’s DC. ... use the caster’s DC. ... the counteract
> check modifier is your spellcasting ability modifier plus your
> spellcasting proficiency bonus, plus any bonuses and penalties that
> specifically apply to counteract checks. If an effect is a
> spell, its level is the counteract level.
>
> Critical Success - Counteract the target if its counteract level is no
> more than 3 levels higher than your effect’s counteract level.

Say we have a Wizard who of course started his career at level 1 with 18 Int, and raises it at every attribute raising level. Now say both the Wizard and a baddie meet up at level 5. Baddie tries to cast [fireball](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=119). The GM rules (as per above) that an ice spell can be used to counter it. The Wizard happens to have the level 1 spell [Snowball](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=540) prepared. What are the Wizard's odds of getting that Critical Success he needs?

Now say they meet again at level 20. Baddie heightens his fireball to a 10th level spell. Our Wizard, knowing he could face 10th level spells, has Snowball prepared into a 7th level spot. Now what are the Wizard's odds of counteracting that fireball spell cast?

Comment: 2 things real quick: 1) I'm pretty sure you can't Counterspell with a cantrip. It reads: "You **lose your spell slot**", which definitionally excludes cantrips. You can probably just replace it with Snowball in your question, heightened to appropriate levels. 2) Is the GM waiving the -2 penalty because you are using an "especially appropriate" spell?

Comment: @ESCE - 1) I was indeed wondering about that. The way its phrased one could argue that losing the slot just doesn't apply if its a cantrip with no spell slot to lose, but I'm fairly new to reading P2E rules, so I'll bow to expertise on the matter. The sentence that talks directly about what qualifies just says "prepared spell", which cantrips are. Seems like it might be a good thing to put in an answer. But yeah, if it makes you feel on surer ground, work it from a lvl 1 spell.

Comment: @ESCE - 2) I'm gonna assume the "normal" case I'm interested in it won't be waived, but if both cases are talked about in an answer, that wouldn't hurt my feelings.

Comment: @ESCE - 1-b) Rereading the counterspell feat text, one could also argue that you lose a spell slot the level of the *triggering* spell. That's the level of slot you'd lose if you had cast the actual triggering spell. However, that wouldn't make much sense if you took just that feat, countered with a lower-level spell, and don't have that same spell prepared at the level of the triggering spell (or perhaps don't even *have* slots that high)

Comment: Re: 1-b): the wording is a bit ambiguous there admittedly, that itself might make for an interesting (separate) question. I think that the RAI is pretty clear, though, that you shouldn't have to expend the exact same level of spell as the opposing caster. But I think we have enough to make an answer now - it'll take some maths and charting so I wouldn't expect one quickly :).

Comment: Voting to close because it's unclear to me which question is being asked. It starts with "how useful are lower level spell for Counterspell" but then the example uses cantrips for some reason. Given that cantrips are not  'lower level spells' for counteracting purposes the example doesn't line up with the explicit question at all, instead it implies a different question: "can you Counterspell with cantrips".

Comment: @Ruse - Its using a cantrip as an example, as it is as low a level spell as its possible to cast. I didn't say "cantrip" in the title specifically for the reason ESCE mentioned (its unclear if they are usable). Is the text of the question itself unclear? How would you suggest editing to clarify this?

Comment: @T.E.D. in the current example it's a 3rd level ray of frost (automatically heightened) vs a 3rd level fireball: both spells are the same level, hence the confusion when the question is about "Counterspelling with a low***er***-level spell". I'd suggest the same thing as ESCE, 1st or 2nd level snowball vs 3rd level fireball: the spell levels are actually different and the cantrip isn't a confounding factor.

Comment: And to be clear, when they meet again at 20th level it's a 10th level ray of frost (automatically heightened) vs a 10th level fireball: both spells are still of the same level.

Comment: Leaving this question open, the body should be answerable at this point. Maybe you'd want to adjust the title to reduce ambiguity.

Comment: @Ruse - You've convinced me to take ESCE's advice and remove the stuff about cantrips in favor of using Snowball as the example spell. Is this better?

Answer (score 5):

### The Odds are Low

- Using the level 5 [necromancer](https://2e.aonprd.com/NPCs.aspx?ID=929) DC of 21 (just below the [High](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=1020) DC for a creature of that level)
- Our wizard's +11 trained spellcasting proficiency plus 19 Intelligence counteract modifier
- The -2 penalty as they aren't casting something more specific like *snowball-that-puts-out-fireballs*
- And that they need a Critical Success to counterspell the 3rd-level *fireball* using their 1st-level *snowball*

We can calculate that the wizard would need to roll a nat 20 to counterspell the *fireball*, as that bumps the degree of success up one step to a critical success. This is the same across all spell DC categories here, even an opponent with a moderate DC of 19 would still require that the wizard rolls a nat 20 to counterspell.

Higher levels do help a bit:

- Using the level 20 [pit fiend](https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=114) DC of 42 (exactly the High DC for a creature of that level)
- Our wizard's +35 legendary spellcasting proficiency plus 24 Intelligence (Apex item assumed) counteract modifier
- The -2 penalty
- Critical Success still required

This time our wizard is able to counterspell on a roll of 19 using a 7th-level *snowball* against a 10th-level *fireball*. But at this higher level the math is much tighter, and could be altered if the opposed creature had a lowered or higher spell DC.

The minimum assuming nothing beyond an Extreme DC would be counterspelling on nat 20's only, but the maximum chance assuming the lowest Moderate DC at 39 would be counterspelling on a rolled 16 or higher, or a 25% to 5% chance at 20th level depending on the opponent.